# Problems with using a jQuery text resizer in IE (jFontSize)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

I am having trouble with getting a text resizer working in IE 8-9, the best plugin I found is called jFontSize.

I have it working in every browser except these 2 versions of IE.

I have included this jFiddle...http://jsfiddle.net/GZyxJ/

I would very much appreciate a response, I understand it's probably something silly as I'm still learning. The website is also built in HTML 5 and I have included jquery 1.9.1

Thanks!

```
<div class="size"> 
                <span>Change Font Size:-</span>
                <a class="jfontsize-button" id="jfontsize-minus" title="decrease font" href="#">A-</a>
                <a class="jfontsize-button" id="jfontsize-default" title="reset default font" href="#">A</a>
                <a class="jfontsize-button" id="jfontsize-plus" title="increase font" href="#">A+</a>

            </div>

(function($){
    $.fn.jfontsize = function(opcoes) {
        var $this=$(this);
        var defaults = {
            btnMinusClasseId: '#jfontsize-minus',
            btnDefaultClasseId: '#jfontsize-default',
            btnPlusClasseId: '#jfontsize-plus',
            btnMinusMaxHits: 5,
            btnPlusMaxHits: 5,
            sizeChange: 1
        };

        if(($.isArray(opcoes))||(!opcoes)){
            opcoes = $.extend(defaults, opcoes);
        } else {
            defaults.sizeChange = opcoes;
            opcoes = defaults;
        }

        var limite=new Array();
        var fontsize_padrao=new Array();

        $(this).each(function(i){
            limite[i]=0;
            fontsize_padrao[i];
        })

        $('#jfontsize-minus, #jfontsize-default, #jfontsize-plus').removeAttr('href');
        $('#jfontsize-minus, #jfontsize-default, #jfontsize-plus').css('cursor', 'pointer');

        /* Ação do Botão A- */
        $('#jfontsize-minus').click(function(){
            $this.each(function(i){
                if (limite[i]>(-(opcoes.btnMinusMaxHits))){
                    fontsize_padrao[i]=$(this).css('font-size');
                    fontsize_padrao[i]=fontsize_padrao[i].replace('px', '');
                    fontsize=$(this).css('font-size');
                    fontsize=parseInt(fontsize.replace('px', ''));
                    fontsize=fontsize-(opcoes.sizeChange);
                    fontsize_padrao[i]=fontsize_padrao[i]-(limite[i]*opcoes.sizeChange);
                    limite[i]--;
                    $(this).css('font-size', fontsize+'px');
                }
            })
        })

        /* Ação do Botão A */
        $('#jfontsize-default').click(function(){
            $this.each(function(i){
                limite[i]=0;
                $(this).css('font-size', fontsize_padrao[i]+'px');
            })
        })

        /* Ação do Botão A+ */
        $('#jfontsize-plus').click(function(){
            $this.each(function(i){
                if (limite[i]<opcoes.btnPlusMaxHits){
                    fontsize_padrao[i]=$(this).css('font-size');
                    fontsize_padrao[i]=fontsize_padrao[i].replace('px', '');
                    fontsize=$(this).css('font-size');
                    fontsize=parseInt(fontsize.replace('px', ''));
                    fontsize=fontsize+opcoes.sizeChange;
                    fontsize_padrao[i]=fontsize_padrao[i]-(limite[i]*opcoes.sizeChange);
                    limite[i]++;
                    $(this).css('font-size', fontsize+'px');
                }
            })
        })
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not included jQuery in the Fiddle. Select it from the dropdown on the left.

Also, the way you were calling the `$('p').jfontsize();` function meant that it was being called before the plugin was added.

[Updated, working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GZyxJ/1/)

Comment: Thank you for the working fiddle. I wasn't entirely sure how to do that, now I am. The example fiddle works in IE however my website still doesn't. I have matched the code.